# Jdeveloper 12C MAF running extremely slow on MAC 10.9

Tags: macos, performance, jdeveloper, oracle-maf

Jdeveloper 12.1.3.0 
MAC OSx 10.9

All of a sudden Jdeveloper is running extremely slow. Typing is almost impossible as I have to stop a few sec after typing a character! The "Close application" from menu takes about 15/20 minutes to complete. However deployment to Simulator time had not increased that much. Earlier I had difficulty in loading Jdeveloper alone with debugging true. The LEVEL.FINE is logger was not possible.

Even without debugging, can anyone help me to run the editor normally? I have 16GB memory on this MacBook pro. How can I utilize this? This slowing down phenomenon  seems to come and go. I have checked the analyzer utility, this happens even when not many processes running on the mac. Has anyone experienced JDeveloper 12C slowing on Mac?

Thanks